# Reset autoincrement in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm running my DB on MYSQL community version 8.0.20. I want to reset a column's autoincrement value back to 1. I looked around and tried doing this

`ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = value;`

but it didn't work. I read that there's no actual way to reset the autoincrement value and that makes sense as it would affect data integrity. But I wanted to use this for a table that has no dependencies at all. How can I reset the value? I was thinking of dropping and recreating the table exactly as it is with all of it's columns and types (I don't need to retain the records)
Is there really a way to reset the auto increment value directly? If not, what is the easiest way I can drop and recreate the table in MYSQL Workbench.

Comment: can you add some description on why it didn't work? error / tables schema, etc. did you try to set the auto_increment to an already taken PK ID?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you cannot "modify" existing rows with this command. If you truncate the table and use this command on the empty table it works as expected

Comment: Yeah I wanted to delete all records and reset auto increment. I didn't know about the "Truncate" command. Will try that, thanks! @ClausBönnhoff